# How to reset the random number generator in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

OpenCV keeps random number generators in thread-local storage and reuses them between function calls. This can lead to inconsistent results between different call sequences.

In OpenCV 2.1, the variable `tlsRNGKey` is defined in cxrand.cpp and not exposed through the headers.

Am I missing something? I can't be the first person to need reproducible clustering results, can I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
cv::theRNG().state = your_seed;
```

Comment: Andrey, this is interesting. Can it be added to OpenCV docs? I did not see it there.

Comment: @vasile I think it is intentionally not documented because the field is specific for current multiply-with-carry implementation.